# Confused, Invalid syntax line 30 Django views

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I was running the manage.py server and when I saved views.py it through a syntax error at line 30. I have been staring at the code for quite a while trying to figure out the issue and I am drawing a blank. Please look at this and get back to me.

views.py:

```
    from django.contrib import messages
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.shortcuts import render

    from . import forms



 def clock_in_view(request):
    form = forms.ClockInForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ClockInForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('continue')       
    return render(request, 'clockinform.html', {'form': form})  



def contact_form(request):
    form = forms.ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form.ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            send_mail(
                'Email from {}'.format(form.cleaned_data['name'],
                form.cleaned_data['message'],
                '{name} <{email}>'.format(**form.cleaned_data),
                ['Gerald@example.com']
            )
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "Message sent!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contact'))
    return render(request, 'contactform.html', {'form': form})
```

the exact error is:

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "Message sent!")
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis for `format(form.cleaned_data['name'], ...`

Answer (score 5):

`'Email from {}'.format(form.cleaned_data['name'],` is missing the closing `)`